# laravel 5.0 collection get method gives 999 records

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

Can anyone help me to get all the records. I'm facing one issue that I'm not able to get all records using with where clause

`Model::where('key', 'value')->get()`

How to get all records using get. I did not get any solutions by googling..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried doing a diedump?

If I try

```
dd(Week::where('price', '0')->get());
```

I get a collection with 17158 array items.

```
Collection {#17158 ▼
  #items: array:16882 [▼
    0 => Week {#17159 …21}
    1 => Week {#17160 …21}
    2 => Week {#17161 …21}
    3 => Week {#17162 …21}
    4 => Week {#17163 …21}
    etc.
```

Comment: Thanks for reply. I checked again on my local it gives me all records but when I check this on live server (online) then it gives me 999 records :(

Comment: getting issue, there is post field limit on online server so in post field limit it gives me only 999 ids... @PaulWright thanks for help